# 'pip' is not recognized after trying to upgrade it in pycharm

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pycharm

Pip was working fine. I used it through the terminal in pycharm to install various packages. Pycharm told me to upgrade pip using a pip command. After doing so an error was thrown out. And now I get the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'" in pycharm and the message "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." in cmd. From what I have read it is because I used a different terminal and it wasn't located in the right place. The fix apprently, use get-pip.py. After trying this, it still doesn't work. I'm not very clued up on how this all works, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pip` to your `path`.

For Windows there is a simple step by step tutorial on YT:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTUlp6L2zkw

Or have a look here:
https://windowsreport.com/pip-not-recognized/